# Parallelize checking of dead URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, python-asyncio

The question is quite easy: Is it possible to test a list of URLs and store in a list only dead URLs (response code > 400) using asynchronous function?

I previously use `requests` library to do it and it works great but I have a big list of URLs to test and if I do it sequentially it takes more than 1 hour.

I saw a lot of article on how to make parallels requests using `asyncio` and `aiohttp` but I didn't see many things about how to test URLs with these libraries.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Multithreading is ideal for this. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multithreading you could do it like this:

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

results = dict()

# test the given url 
# add url and status code to the results dictionary if GET succeeds but status code >= 400
# also add url to results dictionary if an exception arises with full exception details
def test_url(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code >= 400:
            results[url] = f'{r.status_code=}'
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        results[url] = str(e)

# return a list of URLs to be checked. probably get these from a file in reality
def get_list_of_urls():
    return ['https://facebook.com', 'https://google.com', 'http://google.com/nonsense', 'http://goooglyeyes.org']

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(test_url, get_list_of_urls())
    print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using aiohttp and asyncio.

Could be done more pythonic I guess but this should work.

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

urls = ['url1', 'url2']


async def test_url(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        if resp.status > 400:
            return url



async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(test_url(session, url)))
        dead_urls = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print(dead_urls)
        
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Very basic example, but this is how I would solve it:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from asyncio import create_task, gather, run

async def TestUrl(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        if response.status >= 400:
            r = await response.text()
            print(f"Site: {url} is dead, response code: {str(response.status)} response text: {r}")

async def TestUrls(urls):
    resultsList: list = []
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        # Maybe some rate limiting?
        partitionTasks: list = [
             create_task(TestUrl(url, session))
             for url in urls]
        resultsList.append(await gather(*partitionTasks, return_exceptions=False))
    # do stuff with the results or return?
    return(resultsList)

async def main():
    urls = []
    test = await TestUrls(urls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ThreadPoolExecutor

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests

url_list=[
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.adsadasdad.com",
    "https://www.14fsdfsff.com",
    "https://www.ggr723tg.com",
    "https://www.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.com",
    "https://www.78sdf8sf5sf45sf.com",
    "https://www.wikipedia.com",
    "https://www.464dfgdfg235345.com",
    "https://www.tttllldjfh.com",
    "https://www.qqqqqqqqqq456.com"
]

def check(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code < 400:
        print(f"{url} is ALIVE")

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as e:
    for url in url_list:
        e.submit(check, url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing could be the better option for your problem.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Manager
import requests

def checkURLStatus(url, url_status):
    res = requests.get(url)
    if res.status_code >= 400:
        url_status[url] = "Inactive"
    else:
        url_status[url] = "Active"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = [
    "https://www.google.com"
    ]
    manager = Manager()
    # to store the results for later usage
    url_status = manager.dict()

    procs = []

    for url in urls:
        proc = Process(target=checkURLStatus, args=(url, url_status))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()
    
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
    print(url_status.values())
```

**url_status** is a shared variable to store data for separate threads. Refer [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) for more info.

Comment: Disagree. Multiprocessing is too cumbersome for this. Bear in mind that HTTP requests are essentially I/O operations which suits the multithreading paradigm very well. Multiprocessing comes into its own when the various processes are CPU intensive and that is not the case here. You also refer to threads in your description but you're not actually doing any threading. You should also use Manager as context managed